# Extracting Catch Clause Using ASTParser in Java Source code

Tags: java, parsing

I am using Java ASTParser to parse my java code. I am using following code. Using this code I am able to extract "if" & "try" statements. But I am not able to extract "catch clause". Does any one have any idea how to extract catch-clause separately in this. Following code is not giving any error, but its not printing anything in catch clause.

```
public static void methodVisitor(String content) 
{
   //debug("entering met visitor", "1");
   ASTParser metparse = ASTParser.newParser(AST.JLS3);
   metparse.setSource(content.toCharArray());
   metparse.setKind(ASTParser.K_STATEMENTS);
   Block block = (Block) metparse.createAST(null);

   block.accept(new ASTVisitor() {

      public boolean visit(IfStatement myif) {          
         System.out.println("myif="+myif.toString());
         return false;
      }


      public boolean visit(TryStatement mytry) {           
         System.out.println("mytry="+mytry.toString());
         return false;
      }

      public boolean visit(CatchClause mycatch) {                     
         System.out.println("mycatch="+mycatch.toString());
         return false;
      }

   });
}
```

Following is the example code that I am trying to query:

```
     public class Clock2 extends Applet implements Runnable {
     private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
      Thread timer;                // The thread that displays clock
   int lastxs, lastys, lastxm,
    lastym, lastxh, lastyh;  // Dimensions used to draw hands
SimpleDateFormat formatter;  // Formats the date displayed
String lastdate;             // String to hold date displayed
Font clockFaceFont;          // Font for number display on clock
Date currentDate;            // Used to get date to display
Color handColor;             // Color of main hands and dial
Color numberColor;           // Color of second hand and numbers

@Override
public void init() {
    lastxs = lastys = lastxm = lastym = lastxh = lastyh = 0;
    formatter = new SimpleDateFormat ("EEE MMM dd hh:mm:ss yyyy", Locale.getDefault());
    currentDate = new Date();
    lastdate = formatter.format(currentDate);
    clockFaceFont = new Font("Serif", Font.PLAIN, 14);
    handColor = Color.blue;
    numberColor = Color.darkGray;

    try {
        setBackground(new Color(Integer.parseInt(getParameter("bgcolor"),16)));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // Ignore
    }
    try {
        handColor = new Color(Integer.parseInt(getParameter("fgcolor1"),16));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // Ignore
    }
    try {
        numberColor = new Color(Integer.parseInt(getParameter("fgcolor2"),16));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // Ignore
    }
    resize(300,300);              // Set clock window size
}
```

}

Comment: Example code of what you are trying to query?

Comment: Have you tried finding the catch clauses as part of the try statement?

Comment: yes! I tried and actually its working. I identified that problem is happening when I have try-catch block nested in "if-statement". In those cases my code is not able to detect "try" block.

Comment: Uh, `try` or `catch` clause? Is this the same issue as in your question or a separate one? Is this resolved now?

Answer (score 1):

it's because after visiting your `IfStatement` node your return false, so the parser does not explore inside your node.

return true and it will work.

```
  public boolean visit(IfStatement myif) {          
     System.out.println("myif="+myif.toString());
     return true;
  }
```