# How to decipher the argument of Color constructor?

Tags: java, colors

I have made a program in java to make an analog clock quite similar to the code attached in this link
[Extracting Catch Clause Using ASTParser in Java Source code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25340834/extracting-catch-clause-using-astparser-in-java-source-code)

The program runs alright but I can't understand the part written

`handColor=new Color(Integer.parseInt(getParameter("fgcolor1"),16));`

What is fgcolor1 and why are we converting it to integer and what is 16?

Comment: [Here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt(java.lang.String,%20int)) and [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Color.html#Color(int)). `getParameter` probably reads a hex color value mapped to the name `fgcolor1` but there's not enough information to tell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `16` passed as the second parameter to [`Integer.parseInt`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt(java.lang.String,int)) is the `radix`. 16 means the input is expected to be in base 16, in other words a hexadecimal number.

So, it seems that `"fgcolor1"` is the name of a parameter, and the value of this parameter is a String that represents a hexadecimal number representing the color.

This is not an unusual representation, see for example [Convert RGB Color to HEX color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52148457/convert-rgb-color-to-hex-color)

The constructor of [`java.awt.Color`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.desktop/java/awt/Color.html#%3Cinit%3E(int)) accepts such an integer value:

> Creates an opaque sRGB color with the specified combined RGB value consisting of the red component in bits 16-23, the green component in bits 8-15, and the blue component in bits 0-7